# CSV writing - split rows into multiple columns

Tags: python, csv

Sorry if this question is repeated but I searched and could not find a simple example.

I'm trying to write dictionary values to csv file. Here is python code:

```
w = csv.writer(open("../log.csv", "w"))
alphanum = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4, 'ZA':27, 'ZB':28, 'ZC':29, 'ZD':30}
for key, val in sorted (alphanum.items()):
  w.writerow([key, val])
```

Here is the output in the csv file:

```
|---------|---------|
|    A    |     1   |
|    B    |     2   |
|    C    |     3   |
|    D    |     4   |
|    ZA   |     27  |
|    ZB   |     28  |
|    ZC   |     29  |
|    ZD   |     30  |
|---------|---------|
```

But I want to split the rows and write in the following format:

```
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|    A    |    1    |    ZA   |    27   |
|    B    |    2    |    ZB   |    28   |
|    C    |    3    |    ZC   |    29   |
|    D    |    4    |    ZD   |    30   |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

After additional clarification, here is the solution that you were looking for:

```py
import csv

w = csv.writer(open("../log.csv", "w"))
alphanum = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4, 'ZA':27, 'ZB':28, 'ZC':29, 'ZD':30}
alphanum_size = len(alphanum)  
sorted_alphanum = sorted(alphanum.items())
for i in range(int(alphanum_size / 2)):
    w.writerow(sorted_alphanum[i] + sorted_alphanum[i + 4]) if i + 4 < alphanum_size else w.writerow(sorted_alphanum[i])
# Corner case - size is odd and len != 0, write last k: v pair
if alphanum_size % 2 and alphanum_size:  
    w.writerow(sorted_alphanum[-1])
```

AS you can see, we are assigning size of the dictionary to a variable `alphanum_size`, to avoid excessive `len()` function calls in the `for` loop, which would hinder efficiency somewhat.

We have also used a [ternary operator](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) in the for loop. It is equivalent to:

```py
if i + 4 < alphanum_size:
    w.writerow(sorted_alphanum[i] + sorted_alphanum[i + 4])
else:
    w.writerow(sorted_alphanum[i]
```

---

The easiest way would be to change your data container, and basically turn it into a `list` of `dict`s.

```py
w = open("../log.csv", "w")
alphanum = [{'col1': 'A', 'col2': 1, 'col3': 'ZA', 'col4': 27},
            {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 2, 'col3': 'ZB', 'col4': 28},
            ...]
```

Then, you can perform the write operation easily with a `DictWriter`.

```py
header_columns = alphanum[0].keys()
writer = csv.DictWriter(w, header_columns)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(alphanum)
```

An additional improvement that could be done here is to use a context manager instead of a regular file `open()`. You can read up on those [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).

Comment: Some clarification: column1, column2 ... are not in the dictionary, I have written them for reference to show how it looks in the csv file when opened in excel format. The dictionary values that I'm trying to write are huge, so not sure if i need to turn it into a list, which adds another concern i.e., if it messes up the ordering.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve, though? It is not clearly stated in your question, and if the dataset is bigger than the one provided in the example, it would be good to know what needs to be done to provide appropriate efficient solution. From the question I concluded that you want to have a separate column for each string depending on its length, but I am not sure anymore.

Comment: stackexchange: I agree with @Epion, you need to specify what you want in general terms in order to be able to write code that can handle different cases.

Comment: Sry for not being clear. All I need is: 1) alphanum is a dictionary and not interested to change it to list. No changes to the alphanum. 2) column1, column2 ... are only for reference as mentioned in the previous comment and don't want to add any new element to the dictionary or a list. 3) In the question, the output that I'm able to generate has 8 rows and 2 columns. But I want to change it to 4 rows and 4 columns as shown in second format. 4) Once I write to a csv file, I open that file in MS excel to view and I'm interested to see the results in 4 rows and 4 columns as shown in format 2.

Comment: Got rid of column1, column2 in the question for more clarity.

Comment: I can write you a solution that will work for 8 rows, but it will not be universal, nor scale to the huge scale that you mentioned. Basic question that you did not yet clarify:
What is the rule for placing data in a separate column?

Comment: after every 4 rows, place the data in the next column.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. I have provided an edited solution for that works under described ruleset